# Displaying a hierarchical folder structure as a flat list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am making an iOS app, and I have a data structure of the following rough form:

```
struct Folder: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var label: String
    var items: [Item]
    var children: [Folder]
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), label: String, items: [Item] = [], children: [Folder] = []) {
        self.id = id
        self.label = label
        self.items = items
        self.children = children
    }
}
```

Using this, it's fairly straightforward to create a `View` that lets the user traverse the folder structure. But suppose I want to create another `View` that consists of a searchable `List` which shows all of the `Item`s in all of the sub`Folder`s in a single `Folder` structure (but as a *flat* list). Does SwiftUI have a straightforward way of doing this?

I know that `List` supports hierarchical lists, if you're willing to make both Folders and Items the same data structure and just nest them. But I don't want to do this. So am I forced to recursively iterate over the subfolders somehow? Or is there something more clever I can do?

Comment: you could look into using `OutlineGroup` inside a `List` to display recursive data, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/outlinegroup

Comment: The problem with OutlineGroup is that it still preserves the hierarchical format of the list. I want the `Item`s to be displayed flat.

Comment: `I want the Items to be displayed flat.`, well IMHO, there nothing wrong
 with recursion, it's only 3 lines of code and works very well. There are
 more efficient data structures, and `fancy` algorithms to traverse them, eg. tree structures,
 but for some reasonable size list, that is part of a UI, I would do the recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a computed variable that is a Flat representation of a Folder, obviously it use recursion under the hood, but in a Swift way.

```
struct Folder: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var items: [Int]
    let children: [Folder]
    
    init(items: [Int], children: [Folder]) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.items = items
        self.children = children
    }
    
    var flatList: [Int] {
        var items = items
        items.append(contentsOf: children.flatMap { $0.flatList })
        return items
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var parentFolder: Folder = Folder(items: [0, 1, 2, 3], children: [
        Folder(items: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], children: [
            Folder(items: [9, 10, 11, 12], children: [])
        ])
    ])
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(parentFolder.flatList, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you change your folder SwiftUI automatically re-design the view and use the updated flatList content.